# How to adjust vertical alignment in a flex table

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to generate a flex table in HTML using R Markdown that has several cells that are merged across multiple rows using `ReporteRs::spanFlexTableRows()`. However, when I merge the cells together, the numbers displayed in the merged cells appear at the top of the cells. Moreover, the border between the two sets of (adjacent) merged cells disappears. I would like to know:

1. How to center the contents of each merged cell vertically, and
2. How to retain the border between the two merged cells

The following R script illustrates the issue I am having:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ReporteRs)
mtcars[1:4,] %>%
mutate(
  x = row.names(mtcars[1:4,]),
  var1 = 1,
  var2 = 2
) %>%
select(
  x, mpg, cyl, disp, var1, var2
) %>%
make_ft %>%
spanFlexTableRows(j=5, from=1, to= 4) %>%
spanFlexTableRows(j=6, from=1, to= 4)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution to a closely related question -- merging and vertical alignment using officer/flextable rather than ReporteRs. Since officer/flextable are intended to replace ReporteRs I think this is reasonable to post here.

Vertical alignment can intuitively be done in the github (as of 2019-02-10) version of flextable using valign():

```
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

mtcars[1:4,] %>%
  mutate(
    x = row.names(mtcars[1:4,]),
    var1 = 1,
    var2 = 2
  ) %>%
  select(
    x, mpg, cyl, disp, var1, var2
  ) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  flextable::merge_at(j=5, i=1:4) %>%
  flextable::merge_at(j=6, i=1:4) %>%
  valign(j = 5:6, valign = 'top') -> myft
myft
```

Vertical alignment in flextable was historically (as of 2019-02-10 CRAN version) part of the flextable::rotate() function. Here's your example:

```
library(tidyverse)
# library(ReporteRs)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

# turn into flextable, merge and apply a vertical alignment 
# (note that center vertical alignment appears to be the default in flextables 
# so despite your goals i do top alignment here)
mtcars[1:4,] %>%
  mutate(
    x = row.names(mtcars[1:4,]),
    var1 = 1,
    var2 = 2
  ) %>%
  select(
    x, mpg, cyl, disp, var1, var2
  ) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  flextable::merge_at(j=5, i=1:4) %>%
  flextable::merge_at(j=6, i=1:4) %>%
  rotate(j = 5:6, align = 'top', rotation = 'tblr') -> myft

# write to a docx using officer
doc = read_docx()
doc = flextable::body_add_flextable( doc, myft )
print(doc, target = "ftex.docx" )
```

Comment: thanks, your answer motivated the new function `valign` so that call to rotate is not necessary - I found it not intuitive when I read your answer (it's only available in github for now).

Comment: @DavidGohel thanks - i updated my answer - that will make it a lot easier! btw, great work on your packages, incredibly useful.